# Search option in solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have 3 Projects and lots of files and folders in my Solution Explorer. In Migration folder i want to search for the files whose filename containing the words like **lastcreatedat** i.e In normal search option we type like *lastcreatedat* (i.e * followed by the word to be searched, followed by *). Where can i find the search option in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the solution explorer select your project name
 click on "View Class Diagram"
pres CTL+F and type your search word
by this way you can search in your project classes

Answer (score 1):

I have a blog post that covers how to leverage the *Find in files* ability of Visual Studio: [File search: something I discovered in VS2010](http://techfilth.blogspot.co.nz/2010/12/file-search-something-i-discovered-in.html)

Note that this far surpasses anything WIndows File Explorer can do. It will show you how to specify any folder you like to search within, including folders outside of your solution.